# Serialize EF object without children classes

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

When trying to serialize, the compiler throws an error saying that it can't serialize my EF object because of an `ICollection<ChildrenClass>` property.

**Is there a way to serialize an EF object WITHOUT its children classes?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use AutoMapper and the JsonIgnore attribute on your poco model.

EF Class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChildrenClass> MyChildren { get; set; }
}
```

POCO Model:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<ChildrenClass> MyChildren { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapper:

```
var customer = customerService.GetByID(1);

Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerModel>()
      .ForMember(c => c.MyChildren, o => o.Ignore())

var customerModel = Mapper.Map<CustomerModel>(customer);

var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(customerModel);
```

Or you could just not include the MyChildren property in your model class.

You may also be able to mark up the EF model using MetaData class but I haven't tried it:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetadata))]
public partial class Customer
{
    internal class CustomerMetadata
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<ChildrenClass> MyChildren { get; set; }
    }
}
```